# Conjugacy classes  of elements  in an  amalgam of  finite  groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Are  there  conditions on the  finite groups $A$, $B$, $C$   or  the  morphisms  $A \leftarrow C\rightarrow B$ that restrict  the  number  of  infinite  conjugacy  classes   in the amalgamated  product  $A \overset{C}{*}B$?

Comment: No, unless your group is either finite or infinite dihedral. 

Comment: @Misha, not quite. Consider $A$ and $B$ of order 4 and $C$ of order 2. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your morphisms $A \leftarrow C \rightarrow B$ are injective (which I'm assuming you want, since you say amalgamated product, not pushout), then the group $A\ast_C B$ is a virtually free group. In particular, there will be infinitely many conjugacy classes of infinite elements if the group is not finite or virtually cyclic.

The group will be finite if one of the morphisms is surjective. Otherwise, the index of both morphisms is $>1$. If both indices are $2$, then there is a surjection to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \leftarrow 1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$, and the group is virtually cyclic. In this case, each conjugacy class has finitely many elements.

Otherwise, the group will be virtually free (non-cyclic), and there will be infinitely many conjugacy classes which are infinite. If you'd like more information on this result, have a look at Serre's book [Trees](http://books.google.com/books?id=MOAqeoYlBMQC&lpg=PP1&ots=PdiNCTYCj7&dq=serre%2520trees&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=true).